# How do I install modules in Python on Windows?

Tags: python, module

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Installing modules in Python on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5531850/installing-modules-in-python-on-windows)

The instructions in the documentation aren't helping.  How do I install a module in Python?

Comment: Do you have a specific module you would like to install?

Comment: Do you want us to re-write the instructions for you? could you please be a little more specific?

Comment: dupes?? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5531850/installing-modules-in-python-on-windows

Comment: check my answer for your initial question

Answer (score 3):

If there is `setup.py` source file in module directory, run windows command line utility, change current directory to module directory and write

```
python setup.py install
```

make sure that python bin directory is in your system path variable

Answer (score 2):

The same as everywhere, use `easy_install`. (Still it is somewhat more difficult to use under Windows because the `cmd` shell is far less powerful than `bash`)

Comment: Using easy_install on windows is still rather straightforward

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [pip](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/)