# Getting an error of "No module named oauth2 "

Tags: python-2.7, oauth-2.0

I am trying to run a python tool that will authenticate me to linkedin, in order for me to download my linkedin network so that I might be able to analyze it inside of Gephi. I obtained such a file here:

[linkedin-1-oauth.py from github](https://gist.github.com/ThomasCabrol/4232700)

I cloned that and the two other files he has in the gist. I did this from my terminal by just doing `git clone [url here]` for all 3 of the files. I put my api and secret keys in the corresponding places.

I did a `pip install oauth2` and updated `httplib2` as suggested here:

[pip install oauth2 and update httplib2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7781233/python-why-is-installing-oauth2-so-hard)

I also did this from the command line, which downloaded and installed the files in the same directory as to where I downloaded the linkedin files from gist, just all in my user folder.

When trying `pip install oauth2` and get the following error message:

```
Downloading/unpacking oauth2
  Running setup.py egg_info for package oauth2

Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): httplib2 in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from oauth2)
Installing collected packages: oauth2
  Running setup.py install for oauth2
    error: could not create '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oauth2': Permission denied
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/home/steven/build/oauth2/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --single-version-externally-managed --record /tmp/pip-e2RkcV-record/install-record.txt:
    running install

running build

running build_py

running install_lib

creating /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oauth2

error: could not create '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oauth2': Permission denied

----------------------------------------
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/home/steven/build/oauth2/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --single-version-externally-managed --record /tmp/pip-e2RkcV-record/install-record.txt failed with error code 1
Storing complete log in /home/steven/.pip/pip.log
```

I then tried `easy_install oauth2` and got the following error message:

```
error: can't create or remove files in install directory

The following error occurred while trying to add or remove files in the
installation directory:

    [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/test-easy-install-4349.pth'

The installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or
the distutils default setting) was:

    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/

Perhaps your account does not have write access to this directory?  If the
installation directory is a system-owned directory, you may need to sign in
as the administrator or "root" account.  If you do not have administrative
access to this machine, you may wish to choose a different installation
directory, preferably one that is listed in your PYTHONPATH environment
variable.

For information on other options, you may wish to consult the
documentation at:

  http://packages.python.org/distribute/easy_install.html

Please make the appropriate changes for your system and try again.
```

So then I tried doing `sudo apt-get install oauth2` and it could not be found

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS I did all my sudo update and upgrades before I did anything else this morning. I am running python 2.7

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem by going here:

[python-oauth2](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python-oauth2)

Answer (score 1):

Steps to install python oauth2 library on windows

1. Download http://python-distribute.org/distribute_setup.py and copy wherever python was installed
2. Run "python distribute_setup.py"
3. Download and unzip Oauth2 to a directory. Navigate to this directory.
4. Run "python setup.py install" to install ouath2

Answer (score 0):

if you have python 2.7.10 or higher here is simpler method.
Use 'pip' to install python modules.
Say in my case on windows following does the trick.
C:\Python27\Scripts\pip install ouath2