# Trying to install Swampy for Python.

Tags: python, pip, swampy

So I'm following the 'Think Python' PDF guide and this is my first real hurdle. I tried to follow a guide to install it but it's completely over my head. I know this is vague but if anyone could guide me through it like I'm a pensioner I'd be grateful.

I'm currently using Python 2.7.6. I *think* I downloaded setup tools and PIP but I can't be too sure.

Sorry for the openness and vagueness of this question but I'm quite stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: Since you're on Windows, I suggest you download and run [this installer](https://sites.google.com/site/pydatalog/python/pip-for-windows) for Pip.

Once that's done, if you've downloaded and installed Pip correctly, all you should have to do is open a terminal, type `pip install swampy`, and press return.

In order to test if you've installed Swampy correctly, do the following:

1. Open a command prompt.
2. Type `python` and press return
3. Type `from TurtleWorld import *` and press return.

If you've installed Swampy correctly, you shouldn't see any error messages. If you see something like this `ImportError: No module named TurtleWorld`, Swampy isn't installed correctly yet.

### References:

- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-to-install-pip-on-windows?rq=1) on installing Pip on Windows.
- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5531850/installing-the-swampy-python-module-on-windows?rq=1) on
  installing Swampy on Windows.
- [This page](http://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~pconrad/cs5nm/08F/ex10.html) on setting up Swampy
  from an intro CS course at UCSB.

Comment: Windows. Do I just do it in shell or cmd prompt? Thanks for the help.

Comment: @user2925800: Just type it at a command prompt. This is, once again, assuming that pip is installed correctly - how did you install pip?

Comment: I went to the lfd.uci.edu site and just downloaded it. I didn't do anything else to it.

Comment: Just did the 'pip install swampy' in CMD prompt and nothing unfortunately.

Comment: @user2925800: Okay, since you're on Windows, this method isn't going to work. I'll edit my original answer with a method that will work better for you.

Comment: Oh shit. I just typed in: C:\Python27\Scripts\easy_install.exe swampy and I think it installed :D How do I test it?

Comment: @user2925800: okay, I've added a bit on how to test if Swampy is installed correctly to my original answer.

Comment: I think it's worked. I've got a seperate window called TurtleWorld up and everything's running smoothly now, thanks a lot mate.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download Swampy package tar.gz, extract it:

   `$ tar -zxvf [swampy-package-name]`
2. `cd` to Swampy folder, in command line, you type:

   `$ sudo python setup.py install`
3. run python

   `$ python`

   > > from Swampy.TurtleWorld import *

   - or run follow example of think python

     `$ python polygon.py`

It work by python. some other python version doesn't work.